# error: The name 'Image' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart' and 'package:image/src/image.dart'. -- ambiguous_import

Tags: dart, flutter

How to resolve this Ambiguity error in Dart.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Camera',
  home: Scaffold(
    body: new Container(
      child: _image == null ? Text('No Image to display') : Image.file(_image),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(onPressed:() {
      picker();
    },
    tooltip: 'Pick image',
    child: new Icon(Icons.camera)),
  ),
);
```

ERROR:

> The name 'Image' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart' and 'package:image/src/image.dart'. (ambiguous_import at [camera] lib\packs\reg.certificate.dart:45)

**Image** is defined in the **Flutter Widget library**, and also in the **'package:image/image.dart'**. But I want to refer it from **Flutter Widget library** how to do this?

Here is the image of **package:image/image.dart--> library used for decoding the image**.

[image: **package:image/image.dart**]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you have a file named import such as:

```
Import ‘package:image/image.dart’ as Image;
```

Then the class in that package will be `Image.image`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Do you know how to convert form Widget-Image (coming from material.dart) to Image-Image (coming from Image.dart) - or vice-versa ??

Comment: import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Answer (score 5):

```
 import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try by deleting (i.e. by not importing) the -

```
Import ‘package:image/image.dart’
```

to remove the ambiguity and keeping the code same as before -

```
Image.file(_image),
```

Deleting the **‘package:image/image.dart’** worked fine for me since there was no ambiguity and this time 'Image' was purely  provided by 'package:flutter/material.dart'.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as brendanImage;

var image = await receivePort.first as brendanImage.Image;
var resized = brendanImage.copyResize(image, width: ..);
```

Answer (score 0):

- It’s for duplicate call, where in your own class at file 'package:image/image.dart' you defined **Image** once and in flutter built-in package  ‘package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart’ also defined **Image**
- After importing both file in the same direction you get the error.

  **Solution is you can refactor/rename your "Image" at your own file 'package:image/image.dart'**

  **Another solution is you can use alias like import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;**

  in My case I have renamed **Image** to **Images** at my model class file then problem is solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**If you have conflict between two packages of same** ***method/widgets/class*** . Then , first import your package with a ***variable***  as follows:-

**`import 'package:QualityCheckApp/upgrade/screens/home/navigation_drawer.dart' as nav;`**

Then use your **method/class/widget** with this variable.

**`drawer: nav.NavigationDrawer(),`**