# Flutter ambiguous import of Images

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I have some trouble writing this function in Flutter, where the definition of the type Image seems to come from different packages. If I try changing "Future" to "Future", there still is an error that "ui.Image isn't a type so can't be used as a type argument." How would I fix this?

Comment: does decodeImageFromList returns the same Image type as Future<Image> _loadImage?

Comment: It seems they are both called Image type, but essentially different because they are from a different package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: The name 'Image' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart' and 'package:image/src/image.dart'. -- ambiguous\_import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514344/error-the-name-image-is-defined-in-the-libraries-packageflutter-src-widgets)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you import the `dart:ui` package (the first place where the `Image` class is defined), do it like this:

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

So, when you use an Image from that package, you only need to write `ui.Image`. This is because exists two definitions for `Image` in flutter. As member of ui package and as widget.