# Flutter 'Text' isn't a function. Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to create several containers under a container, but I'm unable to use the Text widget under the row, I tried using row, column, align widget all have been showing same error

```
 Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 525,
                        color: Colors.cyan,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl:
                                        "https://animecorner.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/A-Girl-Her-Guard-Dog-585x390.png?ezimgfmt=rs%3Adevice%2Frscb21-1",
                                    height: 230,
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                                Container(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                  height: 125.0,
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Text("data")
                                    ],
```

[image: reference of image]

Comment: when you hover on Text what did you see?

Comment: 'Text' isn't a function.
Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'Text'.dartinvocation_of_non_function it says this

Comment: Whether the `Text` is used from material package import. Check for the Text source.

Comment: Like @SuganPandurengan said, check in the imports, probably the Text() you are using is not from Material.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem was pretty simple, I imported the package dom.dart, which also had text defined, so it was throwing this error,

Comment: and here's a simple solution to this problem (ambiguity): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701777/flutter-ambiguous-import-of-images#answer-59703930